# A classic rebus and a common phrase

Tags: rebus

What is the common phrase that this classic rebus holds?

```
travel
------
cccccc
```

Comment: I like think the answer is something like `travel / (speed of light)^6`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is

> Overseas travel (the word "travel" over a bunch of the letter c)

Comment: Or it could be vice versa.

Comment: @feelinferrety aye, I thought that after I posted this - hopefully either would be accepted